# The set of all connection on a bundle $E$ is an affine space based on $\Omega^1(\text{End}(E))$.

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

In my Global Analysis course there was the following exercice:

> Show that the set of all connection on a bundle $E\to M$ is a non-trivial affine space based on $\Omega^1(\text{End}(E))$.

My teacher told us to use the fact that this set was convex, i.e. for $\nabla$, $\hat \nabla$, $t\nabla + (1 - t)\hat \nabla$ is also a connection for $t \in [0,1]$. However, I tried to do something and I do not use the convexity. This is what I've done:

Let $\psi_U$ be a local trivialization of $E$ over $U \subset M$. Then we can define a connection $\nabla_U$ on $E|_U$ by declaring
$$\nabla_U s = \psi_U^{-1}(d(\psi_U(s)))$$
for $s \in \Gamma(E)$. Using a partition of unity, a collection of these local covariant derivatives can be sewed into a global covariant derivative. This show the non-emptyness. Then for $\nabla, \hat \nabla$, we have that $\nabla - \hat \nabla$ is a $C^\infty$-linear map and from there it is not too hard to prove the existence of an $a \in \Omega^1(\text{End}(E))$ such that
$$\nabla - \hat \nabla = a.$$

Is my argument correct ? Do we need the convexity somewhere in the proof ?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I think the convexity is used in the partition of unity argument

Comment: @Sqrt, could you explain where it'd use? I admit that it isn't really clear..